# Is there a way to properly format with React-Intl where I don't get this error?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native application where I need the `post_date` that I am getting back from a third-party API to not show up as: `2019-05-10 11:26:39`, but instead display: `x many days ago`.

I tried installing React-Intl and then implementing it in `App.js` like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from "react-navigation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import store from "./store";
import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthScreen";
import WelcomeScreen from "./screens/WelcomeScreen";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";
import DeckScreen from "./screens/DeckScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./screens/SettingsScreen";
import ReviewScreen from "./screens/ReviewScreen";

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator({
    welcome: WelcomeScreen,
    auth: AuthScreen,
    main: {
      screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        map: MapScreen,
        deck: DeckScreen,
        review: {
          screen: createStackNavigator({
            review: ReviewScreen,
            settings: SettingsScreen
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <IntlProvider locale="en">
            <MainNavigator />
          </IntlProvider>
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And in my `DeckScreen.js` like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Platform } from "react-native";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Card, Button } from "react-native-elements";
// import Moment from "react-moment";
import { FormattedRelative } from "react-intl";
import Swipe from "../components/Swipe";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class DeckScreen extends Component {
  renderCard(job) {
    return (
      <Card title={job.title}>
        <View style={{ height: 300 }}>
          <MapView
            scrollEnabled={false}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            cacheEnabled={Platform.OS === "android" ? true : false}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.detailWrapper}>
          <Text>{job.company.id}</Text>
          <FormattedRelative value={job.post_date.toString()} />
        </View>
        <Text>
          {job.description.replace(/<span>/g, "").replace(/<\/span>/g, "")}
        </Text>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

I feel like I am closer to getting what I want with React-Intl than with Momentjs, but I am getting this error:

> console.error: "[React Intl] Error formatting relative time.
>   RangeError: The date value provided to IntlRelativeFormat#format() is
>   not in valid range."

Is my code not formatted properly? Anyone have experience with how to implement `FormattedRelative` from React-Intl?

I know I can use `toDateString()` to get rid of the timestamp portion `2019-05-10 11:26:39` but when I try to implement it via `<FormattedRelative value={job.post_date.toDateString()} />`, I continue to get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert date formate to appropriate millisecond and pass into `FormattedRelative` value props.

```
// convert 2019-05-10 11:26:39. date to millisecond, for example see below code.

 var postDate    = Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); 
 <ul>
     <li><FormattedRelative value={postDate} /></li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
yesterday
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs, I have to use `post_date` as it is one of the properties off the API I am using in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar issue for a long time after upgrading to React-Intl 3.0. Here is a wrapper I made with the help of the [V3 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Upgrade-Guide.md#formattedrelativetime)

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedRelativeTime } from 'react-intl';
import { selectUnit } from '@formatjs/intl-utils';

type Props = {
  value: Date | string | number
};

export default function RelativeTimeWrapper(props: Props) {
  const select = selectUnit(new Date(props.value));

  return (
    <FormattedRelativeTime {...props} {...select} />
  );
}
```

Comment: A wrapper that you made? Or did you just copy it from the formatjs repo?

https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/blob/e0bb34c71e99fd4c68244f3bc668c748b2f18413/packages/intl-utils/src/diff.ts